# How to set property path for Data Binding in Data Template

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate, app.xaml

I have the following `DataTemplate` in my App.xaml file:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OneSettingsEntryTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBlocksStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Text}" />
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxesStyle}"
                 Text="{Binding Content}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and the following class which contains both Binding properties:

```
public class InputText
{
    private string Text { get; set; }
    private string Content { get; set; }

    public InputText(string text, string content)
    {
        Text = text;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

The App.xaml file tells me *Cannot resolve symbol text*.
How can I tell the Data Template, which `class` respectively `source` it should use, so that Binding works?

Comment: Set the `DataType` property?

Comment: @bolkay Yes, but I didn't know how to use it for another class. Fortunately, I've now found a way that works.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a solution that works for me. I knew I needed the `DataType` property but didn't know how to reference it, to another class. It looks like `x:Type` was what I missed:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OneSettingsEntryTemplate" DataType="{x:Type templateHelper:InputText}">
```

If there are better alternatives, please share it.